# PHP Upload images to mysql

Tags: php, upload

i'm trying to upload images to mysql, when i try with this code, it seems like it only manages to insert folder name only, but no image filename in mysql table, can i know what went wrong

```
if ($_POST['submit'])
{
//get file attribute
$name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];


//start upload process
    $location = "avatars/".$name;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE username='$username'");
    }


//image form

    <form action='upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 File: <input type='file' name='myfile'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload!'>
</form>
```

Result from this:
when i try to upload eg, picture.jpg, in the mysql table, it only came out "avatars/" on the column, instead of "avatars/picture.jpg"

Comment: Where is your insert/update query to insert image name in to database table

Comment: use print_r($_FILES) and show us the contents.

Comment: Does the file upload correctly and end up where you expect it to? (ie `avatars/picture.jpg`?)

Comment: Jon - No, it end up "avatars/" instead of "avatars/picture.jpg" like i wanted to. Also the folder avatars did not contain any pictures

Comment: if it doesn't display any error, you should consider that no file is uploaded : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: If the folder didn't contain any images, and the string you are creating doesn't have a file, I would have to go with it not having received the uploaded file. try a `var_dump($_FILES);` near the top and see what's going wrong.

Comment: If you are using linux. You have to set apache write permissions to 'avatars' directory.